# understanding data type in haskell

Tags: haskell, either

I am a haskell new bee. I can't just wrap my head around what is going on here

```
 data NestedList a=Elem a | List [NestedList a] deriving Show

 append::NestedList a->NestedList a->Either String (NestedList a)
 append (Elem x) (Elem y) = Right $ List [Elem x, Elem y]
 append (_) (Elem _)=Left "Elements are not allowed"
 append (Elem _) (_)=Left "Elements are not allowed"
 append (List a) (List b)=List(a++b)`
```

it gives me error

Couldn't match expected type `Either String (NestedList a)'
                with actual type`NestedList a'
    In the return type of a call of `List'
    In the expression: List (a ++ b)
    In an equation for`append':
        append (List a) (List b) = List (a ++ b).

But `data NestedList a=Elem a | List [NestedList a]` doesn't it mean that `NestedList` is of type `Elem` or `List` `of NestedList` and

```
 append::NestedList a->NestedList a->Either String (NestedList a)
```

that append can return either `String` or `NestedList`. Now when I do `List(a++b)` I am returning `List`. It should work isn't it?

My other function flatten

```
flatten ::NestedList a->[a]
flatten (Elem x)=[x]
flatten (List(x:xs))=flatten(x)++flatten(List xs)
--flatten NestedList (x:xs)=flatten(x)++flatten(List xs)
flatten(List [])=[]
```

works fine while its input parameter is also `NestedList` but ghc is fine with  `flatten` `(List(x:xs))` where `List(x:xs)` is also just `List`. why doesn't it complain here? Any inputs?

Comment: BTW, there's no need for `append` to fail in those mixed cases.  You could still return a `NestedList`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to return `Either a b`, you have to use either `Left y` or `Right x`, where `y :: a` and `x :: b`. You correctly used `Left "...."` and `Right` in all but the last pattern:

```
data NestedList a=Elem a | List [NestedList a] deriving Show

append::NestedList a->NestedList a->Either String (NestedList a)
append (Elem x) (Elem y) = Right $ List [Elem x, Elem y]
append (_) (Elem _)      = Left  $ "Elements are not allowed"
append (Elem _) (_)      = Left  $ "Elements are not allowed"
append (List a) (List b) = Right $ List(a++b)
--                         ^^^^^
```